# C++ enable warning for uninitialized variables in classes

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

Lets have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <simd/simd.h>
class X {
public:
    X(int a) : x{a} {} // <-- only x is initialized, y is not

    int x;
    int y;
    simd_double3 d;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    X x(1);
    X* xx = new X(2);
    std::cout<<x.x<<" "<<x.y<<" "<<x.d.x; // <-- y and x.d are used, but not initialized
    std::cout<<xx->x<<" "<<xx->y<<"END\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to emit warning that y in X is not initialized. -Wall, -Wmissing-field-initializers seems to do nothing. It compiles without warnings.
This sample code produces this output:
1 0 6.95323e-310
So even if y is initialized to 0(which is not, because clang analysis marks it as uninitialized), clearly simd_double3 is not initialized to 0.

Also clang analysis mark x.y as uninitialized. (*1st function call argument is an uninitialized value*)

Also, when creating X on heap in release mode, content of x.y is garbage. Second line prints: 2 -1094795586, y is clearly not initialized.

Comment: gcc emits a warning: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65e8d365a206db9f).

Comment: GCC doesn't show the warning when optimizations are disabled: https://wandbox.org/permlink/M8uPXGSiflYSCC7J.

Comment: added optimization O1 than tested O3 ..nothing helps. clang things it is ok.

Comment: static analysis finds it, but I would love to have just simple warning during normal compilation.

Comment: This seems like a bug, GCC emits a warning only if optimization is enabled, otherwise it is silent.

Comment: @Galik It's discussed, e.g., here: [GCC - no warning about an uninitialized array with -O0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51659180/580083).

Comment: Suggested answer doesn't seem to work for simd types and clang analysis correcly mark x.y as uninitialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I check all warnings with clang 8 (last release version) command line:
*clang -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Weverything* 
Check: https://godbolt.org/z/kKp-N5 
Clang hasn't any warnings for uninitialized variables into classes and structs. But using clang-tidy with check **cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init** may be helpful to you.
https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init.html

Comment: I guess you are right: Correct answer is: clang does not have warning for uninitialized variables. This sucks, I was burned with this many times, and I believe I am not alone.. clang-tidy is check that can be easily fooled and often reports false positives.

Comment: to be more clear no warning for uninitialized variables inside classes and structures. It does warn you for using local uninitialized variable.