# gcc not catching blatant uninitialized variable

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, compiler-bug

I'm compiling [this code](https://www.godbolt.org/z/dKxWbboe9) with gcc 11.2.0 and the `-Wuninitialized` switch, but I don't get any warning in spite of `bar_uninitialized` being used uninitialized:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

void foo(int dist, int tank, vector<int>& v)
{
  size_t bar_uninitialized;
  while (bar_uninitialized <= v.size())
  {
    bar_uninitialized++;
    cout << bar_uninitialized << "\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v;
  foo(3, 3, v);
}
```

Is this a gcc compiler bug?

Comment: [Enable optimizations](https://www.godbolt.org/z/b81dqs3zc).  GCC does a much better job at detecting uninitialized variables when it is optimizing, since then it does a much more thorough analysis of the code flow and variable accesses.  Once upon a time, it didn't even try to produce uninitialized warnings unless optimizations were on.  Now it at least tries a little, but it's still not nearly as good without optimizations.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659180/gcc-no-warning-about-an-uninitialized-array-with-o0/51660496#51660496.

Comment: @NateEldredge Effectively, with `O3`, I get the warning, even without commenting the `insert`.

Comment: Not relevant here, but if you plan to use `v` later on, the while condition should probably read `bar_uninitialized < v.size()` so you don't try to access one past the end of `v`.

Comment: @Eike thanks, but yes it's not relevent here, the code I posted is just for demonstration, it has no other purpose,.